# How can I find PVC pipes in a wall?

Tags: pipe, pvc

I would like to find a waste drain PVC pipe that has a standard diameter of 10cm. I noticed this question focuses on metal pipes [Are there devices to find pipes in walls?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/120211/are-there-devices-to-find-pipes-in-walls), but I would like to find a PVC pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspection cameras often incorporate a transmitter which allows you to pinpoint the camera's position with a separate sensor. The typical use case would be locating a defect under a slab or in the ground so you know where to excavate, but there's nothing to prevent you from running the camera down the waste pipe and locating it in the wall that way.

Of course you can often save the rental cost by measuring from known points, educated guesses based on the structure, or listening for a snake banging around in the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

nowadays, inspection cameras for wall/floor cavities etc are cheap. search for boroscopes or endoscopes that plug into smartphone or laptop.   Believe it or not, borescopes can be purchased for as little as $5 plus shipping online.